# sql case expression for repeating values based on number of occurrences in oracle

Tags: sql

I'm trying to see if I can improve on the case statement below or find a better method. The output(WANT) is a always a sequence of 9's based on what the value of HAVE is.

```
Have     Want
1        9
2        99
3        999
4        9999
5        99999
6        999999
7        9999999


Case Have when '1' then '9'
      when '2' then '99'
      when '3' then '999'
      when '4' then '9999'
      when '5' then '99999'
--it keeps going on and on-- for instance a 6 will have 6 9's , a 7 will have 7 9's, a 9 will have 9 9's--
end as Want
```

I'll appreciate a better way to handle this task. The database is in oracle

Note: I finally found a way to get it to work. I thought I share with the team

```
select RPAD('9',LENGTH('9')*(HAVE),'9') from dual
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replicate()` in T-SQL, `repeat()` in MySQL

```
select replicate('9', have_int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` in a sort of database independent way:

```
select substring('999999999999', 1, have)
```

Note:  some databases spell `substring()` as `substr()`.  You can also use `left()` for this purpose.  Or, as the other answer suggests, one of the built-in functions that really do differ by database.